# Sign in the time-independent Schrödinger's equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

In the time-independent Schrödinger's equation:

$$ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2} {dx^2} u + Vu ~= Eu, $$

why there is a minus sign before the first term?

Answer (score 4):

The negative sign arises from the fact that in a quantum theory $\vec{p} \to - i \hbar \nabla$. Thus, the kinetic energy $\frac{p^2}{2m} \to - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2$.

An alternative way to understand this is the following: A typical wave-function with momentum $p$ takes the form $\psi(x) \sim e^{- \frac{i}{\hbar} \vec{p} \cdot \vec{x}}$
$$
- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi \sim - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left( - \frac{i}{\hbar} \vec{p} \right) \cdot \left( - \frac{i}{\hbar} \vec{p} \right) = \frac{p^2}{2m}
$$
Thus, we need a negative sign in the KE part of the Schrodinger equation to give a positive kinetic energy in terms of momentum $\vec{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

And remember that $p^2 = p.p^{\dagger}$.
Now $p^{\dagger} = (-i\hbar)^* \times (\nabla)^{\dagger}$, and $\nabla^{\dagger} = -\nabla$, so $p^{\dagger} = i\hbar\times(-\nabla) = p$. Otherwise you wouldn't have the minus sign :)